# Memory profiler for C

Tags: c, memory, profiler, valgrind

I need a memory profiler to know the memory usage for each function. I know valgrind (Massif) but it doesn't give me information about specific functions (at least, I don't know how to do it with massif)

Do you know any tool for this purpose in Linux?

Thanks!

Comment: Is for heap memory. The code uses a big amount of data and I need to know in wich function is allocating it. Although deallocation can occur in other function, if function A allocates 16Gb and the machine has 8Gb the computer starts swapping (and it doesn't matter if later function B is going to deallocate it).

Comment: Why you need 16 G memory to be allocated at once? I think you should reconsider your requirement and design.

Comment: @Vikram.exe - you're right, but in order to answer that question he needs the results from the profiler :-) (Remember - he may be maintaining code written by someone else, and even if not, real-life behaviour of systems can often be unpredictable :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [MemProf](http://www.secretlabs.de/projects/memprof/).

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to get the location from where large amount of memory is requested, The easiest way would be to patch `malloc` function or create a new library having `malloc` call and track the size form your `malloc function`. I am not talking about implementing the malloc call. LD_PRELOAD this library to your application.

here is a sample code:

```
/*
 * gcc -shared -fPIC foo.c -ldl -Wl,-init,init_lib -o libfoo.so
 *
 * LD_PRELOAD this library in the environment of the target executable
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>

#ifndef RTLD_NEXT
#define RTLD_NEXT ((void *)-1)
#endif

int init_lib(void)
{
    return 0;
}

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    /* do required checks on size here */

    return ((void* (*)(size_t))(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc")))(size);
}
```

You can very well modify this code to do some additional stuff.

Comment: Whosoever down Voted it, could you please give the reason?

Comment: I'm upvoting because this is far from being wrong.

Comment: Thanks Jweyrich, but I am still wondering why it was down voted.

Comment: @Vikram.exe This will not work if printf (or similar function which internally calls malloc) is used inside malloc function. As it will create an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 4):

`Massif` *does* show you which functions were responsible for the memory usage, as long as you've compiled your program with debugging info (`-g`).  It will even show you the line number.

This information is given as a call tree in each *detailed snapshot* under the graph in the `ms_print` output.  The frequency of detailed snapshots can be controlled with the `--detailed-freq` option to massif.  See [Section 9.2.6 of the Massif manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html#ms-manual.thesnapshotdetails) for details on reading the detailed snapshot information.

Comment: The informtaion is not too friendly (as usual in valgrind) but it's true that it provides information about the functions. There is a tool ( massif visualizer http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Massif+Visualizer?content=122409) that seems to solve this with colorful graphics. I have not tried it yet but it looks great in the screenshots!

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out Massif gives exhaustive profiling information, but it considerably slows down the process.

Another option is Google's tcmalloc, which has an embedded heap profiler that dumps the call graph with allocations (see http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/heap_profiler.html), which can also be visualized graphically.

You can link it at runtime with your program with `LD_PRELOAD`, and the `HEAPPROFILE` env variable enables the heap profiler.