# Memory profiling for C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, profiling

*Regarding question duplication*

First of all, I took a look at this stackoverflow question already dealing with the answer: [Memory profiler for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593191/memory-profiler-for-c)

Though the question was targeted at the Linux platform, and it's a couple of years old now. I would also like to deepen the question a bit, hence why I thought it would be acceptable to ask a new question regarding the topic.

**The question**

I'm quite new to the field of doing real profiling for my applications, and I would like to learn how. I've been learning C for a while now (already experienced in languages such as C#/Java), and am now interested in learning how to properly control memory allocation and detection of leakage etc.

So, what is the most commonly used profiler to achieve this for C these days for the windows platform? Is it still MemProf or Massif? Or is there other preferred alternatives?